# Windows service build includes DLL's not referenced

Tags: windows, vb.net, dll, service, csvhelper

Using Visual Studio 2017 I have created a Windows service using VB.net.  I have the root service class and a project installer class.  The Service builds, installs, and runs as expected.  With the following exception - the output to the BIN folder is enormous.
The references listed are as follows:

```
    System
    System.Configuration
    System.Configuration.Install
    System.Deployment
    System.Net.Http
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe
    System.ServiceProcess
    System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions
    TSLogger (internall DLL that logs to Event log)
```

When I build the service the output to the bin folder includes over 100 .NET DLLs.  At different points during development, using NuGet package manager, I have installed and uninstalled CsvHelper and Newtonsoft.Json.

Any idea what would set the compiler to include all these DLLs as part of the output?  Or how I can control it?

I have attached a screenshot of the bin folder.

Bin folder screenshot:
[image: bin folder screenshot]

Comment: The "references" you listed look like they might be namespaces. Can you show your actual references? This list is found in the project under References. That very well could be your comprehensive list of references. I'm just making sure.

Comment: BTW :) the project I'm currently working on has 344 items in the bin folder. So enormous is relative

Comment: Also, it looks like the dlls are all .NET framework dlls. I don't know why they would be deployed. Does your system have the framework version you're developing with installed?

Comment: Thanks djv, the list of references in my question match the Reference Names under 'References' in Project - Properties.   Also, I have developed a number of other services, all of which have properly outputed the expected DLLs.  I just don't know what controls this output and how I can manipulate it back to expectations.

Comment: Are you developing a 64 bit application on a 32 bit machine?

Comment: Thanks for the input and suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out it was CsvHelper v15.0.0. I created a new solution, didn't add any code but just added references and as soon as I added CsvHelper with NuGet Package manager, the bin folder would fill up with all these framework DLLs.

**UPDATE**

I have confirmed I get the same result from CsvHelper version 14.0.0; versions 13.0.0 and 12.3.2 do not produce these results.  I didn't test any other versions.  The only difference I can see is that the latest 2 versions include a reference to System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe - could this be what brings in so much of the .NET Framework libraries??